# How can I add C# language support to Visual Studio 2010 shell?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Greetings,

I'm using Visual Web Developer Express 2010 to do some development; I have also the Visual Studio 2010 Shell installed, which I use to debug server and client code, using the Debug>Attach to process command.

My problem is that C# (.cs) files open in the shell as if they're plain text files; there's no syntax colouring nor value evaluation on mouse hover over properties or values.

Sometimes when I open ASP.Net pages in the shell I get an error message saying "The Visual Studio language support for C# has not been installed. Code-editing IntelliSense will not be available. Markup IntelliSense for server controls may not work".

VB.Net language support is working well in the shell. I get all the features I have in Visual Studio Express.

Is there a way to get C# language support in the shell?

Answer (score 2):

The Express editions of Visual Studio are a little different than the other SKUs (Professional, Ultimate, etc.) in that there are separate products for the various .NET languages.

My guess is that you have Web Developer Express installed, but in order to open C# code files with the full support of the editor (syntax highlighting, debugging, etc.) you need to download and install Visual C# Express. Multiple versions of Visual Studio Express work side-by-side just fine.

See here to download Visual C# Express 2010 free from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CS

Comment: I have the four express products (C#, VB, Cpp and VWD). But I don't mean I have problems with development. My problem is just that when I open .cs files in the Visual Studio shell they're open as if they're plain text files, without syntax colouring and the other language services. How can I install these services to the shell?

Comment: Try going to the Tools menu, and opening the Options dialog. Make sure that "Show all settings" is checked at the bottom, then expand the heading "Text Editor" in the listbox at the left. Click on "File Extension" underneath that heading. To the right, you should be able to associate particular file extensions with an editor (C#, VB, etc.). Maybe that will work for you?

Comment: Neither C# project support nor .cs file editing capability is available in the shell. C# editor is not in the list you mentioned. I fiddled with registry (copied settings from C# express to the shell) and now Visual C# is available in the editors list, and I've associated it with .cs files, but when I open such files, the IDE hangs. I don't know why MS made it this way.

Comment: I was able to get this to work in a solution after installing the Microsoft Light Switch.  If it doesn't work by adding the c# file to a solution it won't work.