# Enable C# projects in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

It seems that C# support has been installed:

[image]

However, there isn't an option to create a C# project:

[image]

Is there a way to enable C# projects without having to reinstall VS?

Note: this question isn't entirely relevant:
[How can I add C# language support to Visual Studio 2010 shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093954/how-can-i-add-c-sharp-language-support-to-visual-studio-2010-shell)

** edit 0 **

I followed the instructions (listed in the comments).  The `*TemplatesCache` directories were recreated (with one named `CSharp` in `ItemTemplatesCache`), however they are not included in the new project list (when VS is restarted).

** edit 1 **

If it is relevant, I have 'Visual Studio 2010 Shell' edition:

[image]

Comment: Somethings wrong, the VB templates aren't there either.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't upgrade to [Visual Studio 2013 Community](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx)? It is free, has many more features, and now has features from the professional version of VS.

Comment: Have you tried [those suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780783/visual-studio-2010-missing-project-item-templates)?

Comment: Close VS. Start by clearing the MEF cache (delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ComponentModelCache`). Then clear the template cache (delete `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache` and `ItemTemplatesCache`). Then run `devenv /InstallVSTemplates` followed by `devenv /setup` for good measure. That might help (and should not affect your settings, etc.). Failing that, try a repair. Failing that, I think a reinstall is your best bet.

Comment: Is it something that used to work or is a fresh install?

Comment: I inherited this workstation--hasn't worked since I've had it.

Comment: It looks like you have [Visual Studio for Applications](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=38807); which does not support desktop, web, mobile, server, nor store applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 Shell is a completely different product from Visual Studio 2010 Express or Professional. The former allows you to create shell applications. The latter allows you to create C# and/or VB programs.

What you need to do is install Visual Studio 2010 Express or Professional.